# Sending Google Play Credits

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to send or 'gift' a person Google play credits?  We would like to allow students to redeem points they earn for good grades, etc for Google play credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Google Play Help pages](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3423016?hl=en):

> You can only purchase Google Play credit to add to your own Google
>   Play balance. At this time, aside from giving someone a physical
>   Google Play gift card, it is not possible to add credit to another
>   user's Google Play balance as a gift.

That said, there are places like [PCGameSupply.com](http://www.pcgamesupply.com/Gift-Cards/Google-Play-Gift-Card/) that allow you to buy "digital" gift cards (Google Play included)- which means the redemption codes are emailed to you rather than a physical card in the mail/store. Just pick "Send as Gift" at checkout. These always seem to come with a caveat though- digital gift cards have an activation fee on top of the face value. Personally whenever I've bought a physical gift card in a store, there wasn't an activation fee.

Alternatively, since I don't know how your points/points redemption system works, you could just buy a stack of physical $10 Google Play gift cards, and once a student has earned enough points to redeem $10 worth, give them one of the gift cards. The cards don't expire, so no need to worry about that.